# Custom domain constraint in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

```
public class Service {

    String reviewChanges
    String comment

    static constraints = {
      reviewChanges (inList:['NO','YES'])
      comment validator: { val, obj ->
        if(reviewChanges=='YES') {
          (nullable:false, blank:false, minSize:1, maxSize:500)
        } else {
          (nullable:true, blank:true, minSize:1, maxSize:500)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Above comment validator does not work for me.
I want if reviewChanges field selected YES then Comment field must be Mandatory field else Comment filed Non-Mandatory

Answer (score 1):

The best way working with custom validators would be like this..

```
static constraints = {
    reviewChanges(inList:['NO','YES'])
    comment validator: { val, obj,errors ->
        if (obj.reviewChanges == 'YES' && StringUtils.isEmpty(val))  { 
            errors.rejectValue('comment',"some.custom.validation.key")
        }
    }
}
```

**errors.rejectValue** will allow you to give proper field errors using propertyName and also you can use it for parameterized error...

```
errors.rejectValue('propertyName','errorCode',errorArgs as Object[],'defaultMessage')
```

and define errorCode is message.properties to access errorArgs like

```
errorCode = This is {0} first parameter being passed as errorArgs.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this I think (I haven't tested this, but you get the idea):

```
static constraints = {
    reviewChanges(inList:['NO','YES'])
    comment validator: { val, obj ->
        if (obj.reviewChanges == 'YES' && StringUtils.isEmpty(val))  { 
            return "some.custom.validation.key"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that may have to be obj.reviewChanges instead of just reviewChanges.

Comment: Good spot, thanks for that. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response rcgeorge23
But solution does not work.
I get below error
 98: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 98, column 26.
           comment validator: { val, obj ->
                            ^

1 error

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a requirement to have `reviewChanges` as a String, I would make it a `Boolean` field and using Groovy truth, you should be able to do something like:

```
class Service {

    Boolean reviewChanges
    String comment

    static constraints = {
       comment nullable:true, minSize:1, maxSize:500, validator: { val, obj ->
          if (obj.reviewChanges && (!val)){
             return "comments.required"
          }
       }
    }
```

}

using Grails 2.3.3